# Right dateFormat for ISO 8601 date

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, iso8601

I have stacked with dateFormat of `2017-12-13T10:30:00.000-06:00` for `NSDateFormatter`. I'd tried different formats but still getting `nil` from `[formatter dateFromString:exampleDate]`. The most possible format I had picked up on [nsdateformatter](http://nsdateformatter.com) was `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` but TimeZone not applying correctly and I got `nil` from `NSDateFormatter`.

I also try to use:

```
NSISO8601DateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSISO8601DateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2017-12-13T10:30:00.000-06:00"];
```

and also got `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSISO8601DateFormatter` with options `.withFractionalSeconds` (iOS 11.0+) and `.withInternetDateTime`

```
NSISO8601DateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSISO8601DateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.formatOptions = NSISO8601DateFormatWithFractionalSeconds | NSISO8601DateFormatWithInternetDateTime;
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2017-12-13T10:30:00.000-06:00"];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

For a standard `NSDateFormatter` the date format is correct

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2017-12-13T10:30:00.000-06:00"];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Comment: damn `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` really worked, I swear it returned `nil` :)

Are you sure time zome is applying correctly with this format?

Comment: When using a plain `NSDateFormatter` be sure you set the formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX` when parsing a fixed format date string.